# Handle open/collapse events of Accordion in Angular

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

If I have this code:

```
<accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
</accordion-group>
```

Using AngularJS, angular-ui and Twitter Bootstrap, is it possible to make the accordion call some action when opened? I know I can't simply add `ng-click`, because that is already used after it's "compiled" to HTML for opening/collapsing of the group.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is the `is-open` attribute on the accordion-group which points to a bindable expression. You could watch this expression and execute some logic when a given accordion group is open. Using this technique you would change your markup to:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" heading="{{group.title}}" is-open="group.open">
   {{group.content}}
</accordion-group>
```

so that you can, in the controller, prepare a desired watch expression:

```
$scope.$watch('groups[0].open', function(isOpen){
    if (isOpen) {
      console.log('First group was opened'); 
    }    
  });
```

While the above works it might be a bit cumbersome to use in practice so if you feel like this could be improved open an issue in https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap

Comment: Could I make the watching more generic? Like - so I don't have to write `'groups[0].open'` for every row. I don't know in advance how many rows I'll have...

Comment: @Michal I'm afraid that with the current implementation is not trivial. You could setup a deep watch as in this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/bLnkvf?p=preview but I can't recommend this really...

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource Do we have the `is-open` option with the `accordion-heading` markup?

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource - thanks for an example. It's certainly doable, bur do you guys plan to to formally add open/close events to Accordion control? Original Bootstrap Collapsible control has ones.

Comment: I can't believe this isn't easier to do. It's complete garbage. Of course a developer would want to watch an accordion for an open group and when it changes. It's trivial.

Comment: Is this really still the current state of this issue? This is unacceptable

Answer (score 35):

Accordion groups also allow for an accordion-heading directive instead of providing it as an attribute. You can use that and then wrap your header in another tag with an ng-click.

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" heading="{{group.title}}" is-open="group.open">
  <accordion-heading>
    <span ng-click="opened(group, $index)">{{group.content}}</span>
  </accordion-heading>
</accordion-group>
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/B3LC1X?p=preview

Comment: Yes, the accordion-heading allows us to open or close panels on click, but it's not an example exposing how to open the panels from other triggers.

Comment: This was the cleanest solution I could find. Thanks, have a beer on me!

Comment: This is nice, the only issue is the accordion heading takes up the entire row, and the opened function will only get called when you click directly on the text

Comment: cool way! +1 

Just beware of giving up in the first try itself by testing the click with alert or some console.log. It won't work, try it with a function present in your scope on the controller :) Reason I understand it doesn't work is because alert and console are not supported on ng-click.

Comment: THANK YOU @AnmolSaraf : I was becoming mad trying to test it with an alert !

Answer (score 32):

Here's a solution based on *pkozlowski.opensource* solution.
Instead of adding a **$watch** on each item of the collection, you can use a **dynamically defined Property**. Here, you can bind the *IsOpened* property of the *group* to the *is-open* attribute.

```html
<accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" heading="{{group.title}}" is-open="group.IsOpened">
   {{group.content}}
</accordion-group>
```

So, you can dynamically add the **IsOpened** property on each item of the collection in the controller :

```js
$scope.groups.forEach(function(item) {
  var isOpened = false;
  Object.defineProperty(item, "IsOpened", {
    get: function() {
      return isOpened;
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
      isOpened = newValue;
      if (isOpened) {
        console.log(item); // do something...
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Using **properties** instead of **watches** is better for performances.

Comment: I know, SO basically discourages *OMG thankyou-thankyou-thankyou* and stuff. So let me instead say, I will buy you a beer if I ever run into you ;) This is a wonderful solution w/o the overhead of the watch.

Comment: This is actually the best answer at present.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution inspired by kjv's answer, which easily tracks which accordion element is open. I found difficult getting `ng-click` to work on the accordion heading, though surrounding the element in a `<span>` tag and adding the ng-click to that worked fine.

Another problem I encountered was, although the `accordion` elements were added to the page programmatically, the content was not. When I tried loading the content using Angular directives(ie. `{{path}}`) linked to a `$scope` variable I would be hit with `undefined`, hence the use of the bellow method which populates the accordion content using the ID `div` embedded within.

**Controller:**

```
    //initialise the open state to false
    $scope.routeDescriptors[index].openState == false

    function opened(index) 
    {
        //we need to track what state the accordion is in
        if ($scope.routeDescriptors[index].openState == true){   //close an accordion
            $scope.routeDescriptors[index].openState == false
        } else {    //open an accordion
            //if the user clicks on another accordion element
            //then the open element will be closed, so this will handle it
            if (typeof $scope.previousAccordionIndex !== 'undefined') {
                $scope.routeDescriptors[$scope.previousAccordionIndex].openState = false;
            }
            $scope.previousAccordionIndex = index;
            $scope.routeDescriptors[index].openState = true;
    }

    function populateDiv(id)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < $scope.routeDescriptors.length; x++)
        {
            $("#_x" + x).html($scope.routeDescriptors[x]);
        }
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
        <div ng-hide="hideDescriptions" class="ng-hide" id="accordionrouteinfo" ng-click="populateDiv()">
            <accordion>
                <accordion-group ng-repeat="path in routeDescriptors track by $index">
                    <accordion-heading>
                        <span ng-click="opened($index)">route {{$index}}</span>
                    </accordion-heading>
                    <!-- Notice these divs are given an ID which corresponds to it's index-->
                    <div id="_x{{$index}}"></div>
                </accordion-group>
            </accordion>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used an associative array to create a relationship between the opened state and the model object.

The HTML is:

```
  <div ng-controller="CaseController as controller">


                <accordion close-others="controller.model.closeOthers">
                    <accordion-group ng-repeat="topic in controller.model.topics track by topic.id" is-open="controller.model.opened[topic.id]">
                       <accordion-heading>
                          <h4 class="panel-title clearfix" ng-click="controller.expand(topic)">
                         <span class="pull-left">{{topic.title}}</span>
                         <span class="pull-right">Updated: {{topic.updatedDate}}</span>
                          </h4>                           
                       </accordion-heading>
                  <div class="panel-body">

                      <div class="btn-group margin-top-10">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="controller.createComment(topic)">Add Comment<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                      </div>
                     <div class="btn-group margin-top-10">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="controller.editTopic(topic)">Edit Topic<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
                     </div>
                      <h4>Topic Description</h4>
                      <p><strong>{{topic.description}}</strong></p>
                      <ul class="list-group">
                          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="comment in topic.comments track by comment.id">
                              <h5>Comment by: {{comment.author}}<span class="pull-right">Updated: <span class="commentDate">{{comment.updatedDate}}</span> | <span class="commentTime">{{comment.updatedTime}}</span></span></h5>
                              <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
                             <div class="btn-group">
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="controller.editComment(topic, comment)">Edit <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="controller.deleteComment(comment)">Delete <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                             </div>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>

                    </accordion-group>
                </accordion>
```

The controller snippet is:

```
   self.model = {
      closeOthers : false,
      opened   : new Array(),
      topics   : undefined
   };
```

The 'topics' are populated on an AJAX call.  Separating the 'opened' state from the model objects that are updated from the server means the state is preserved across refreshes.

I also declare the controller with `ng-controller="CaseController as controller"`

Answer (score 0):

accordion-controller.js

```
MyApp.Controllers
    .controller('AccordionCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.groups = [
            {
                title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
                content: "Dynamic Group Body - 1",
                open: false
            },
            {
                title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
                content: "Dynamic Group Body - 2",
                open: false

            },
            {
                title: "Dynamic Group Header - 3",
                content: "Dynamic Group Body - 3",
                open: false
            }
        ];

        /**
         * Open panel method
         * @param idx {Number} - Array index
         */
        $scope.openPanel = function (idx) {
            if (!$scope.groups[idx].open) {
                console.log("Opened group with idx: " + idx);
                $scope.groups[idx].open = true;
            }
        };

        /**
         * Close panel method
         * @param idx {Number} - Array index
         */
        $scope.closePanel = function (idx) {
            if ($scope.groups[idx].open) {
                console.log("Closed group with idx: " + idx);
                $scope.groups[idx].open = false;
            }
        };

    }]);
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionCtrl">

    <accordion>

        <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="group.open">
            <button ng-click="closePanel($index)">Close me</button>
            {{group.content}}
        </accordion-group>


        <button ng-click="openPanel(0)">Set 1</button>
        <button ng-click="openPanel(1)">Set 2</button>
        <button ng-click="openPanel(2)">Set 3</button>

    </accordion>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it w/ an Angular directive:

## html

```
<div uib-accordion-group is-open="property.display_detail" ng-repeat="property in properties">
  <div uib-accordion-heading ng-click="property.display_detail = ! property.display_detail">
    some heading text
  </div>
  <!-- here is the accordion body -->
  <div ng-init="i=$index">  <!-- I keep track of the index of ng-repeat -->
    <!-- and I call a custom directive -->
    <mydirective mydirective_model="properties" mydirective_index="{% verbatim ng %}{{ i }}{% endverbatim ng %}">
      here is the body
    </mydirective>
  </div>
</div>
```

## js

```
app.directive("mydirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "EAC",  
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      /* note that ng converts everything to camelCase */
      var model = attrs["mydirectiveModel"];
      var index = attrs["mydirectiveIndex"];
      var watched_name = model + "[" + index + "].display_detail"
      scope.$watch(watched_name, function(is_displayed) {
        if (is_displayed) {
          alert("you opened something");
        }
        else {
          alert("you closed something");
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

There are some idiosyncrasies about my setup there (I use Django, hence the "{% verbatim %}" tags), but the method should work.