# angular-ui bootstrap accordion: How do I properly $watch the is-open attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to perform an action when a specific accordion-section is openend. My use-case is almost identical to this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642082/handle-open-collapse-events-of-accordion-in-angular), only I'm using statically defined 's instead of ng-each.

Somehow I can't get the $watch to fire when the is-open state changes, can anybody tell me why this doesn't work:

View:

```
  <accordion close-others="false">
   <accordion-group heading="group1" is-open="acc1open">
    content 1
   </accordion-group>    
   <accordion-group heading="group2" is-open="acc2open">
    content 2
   </accordion-group>  
  </accordion>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.acc1open = false;
  $scope.acc2open = true;

  $scope.$watch('acc1open', function(){
      console.log("watch acc1:" +$scope.acc1open);
  }, true);
```

Here's a plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Ycms81?p=preview

It prints "watch acc1:false" a single time when the page is loaded, but nothing when the accordion group is opened.

Comment: I tried this and couldn't figure it out either..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a `<span>` inside the AccordionDemoCtrl div and changed the is-open to bind to $parent.acc1open

```
<accordion-group heading="group1" is-open="$parent.acc1open">
```

...

```
<span ng-click="acc1open = true">Click me to open group 1</span>
```

Directives have their own scope, and the variables are their own.

Comment: Thanks that was it! Updated Plunker for the record: http://plnkr.co/edit/1lnbTa?p=preview

Comment: This description was iffy for me, so I'll add a comment with how I did this.  The plunker was the solution for me.

Comment: this actually is a wrong answer, you should not associate a single value to multiple is-open. Take a look at the above plunker, it actually is not working.

Answer (score 11):

Along with the plunker: [plnkr.co/edit/1lnbTa?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/1lnbTa?p=preview)

I found this worked for an array:

JS

```
$scope.array = [object1,object2,object3,object4];
$scope.isOpen = [false,false,false,false];
$scope.$watch('isOpen', function() {
  console.log("watch isOpen:" + $scope.isOpen);
}, true);
```

HTML(JADE)

```
accordion-group(ng-repeat='object in array',is-open="$parent.isOpen[$index]")
  accordion-heading
    h4 My Heading {{$index}}
  p My content {{$index}}
```

Comment: I agree, at least put you in the right direction. You can set $scope.isOpen = [true]; so that the first panel is always open. And then it'll fill the rest of elements for you by is-open="isOpen[$index]"

Comment: In order to find the current open panel, you can do _.indexOf($scope.isOpen, true) if you are using underscore.