# How do I detect when Accordion Group has been selected in Angular UI?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, accordion, angular-ui

I am currently using angular ui and trying to detect when the accordion group changes.  So far I have been unable to use jquery to listen to the height changes, etc.  Any ideas?

Here is my code currently (in Jade):

```
accordion(close-others='true')
  accordion-group(ng-repeat='data in dataArray',is-open='data.isOpen==true')
    accordion-heading
      h4 {{data.name}}
    p my body goes here
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle open/collapse events of Accordion in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642082/handle-open-collapse-events-of-accordion-in-angular)

Comment: Repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642082/handle-open-collapse-events-of-accordion-in-angular