# Add ng-click event to angular-ui accordion

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and have started using accordions.

I need to fire an `ng-click` event when someone opens or closes an accordion group.

I did some research and found this thread: [angular-ui issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/179)

It linked to a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vYv7RhKra4j3ruHdwtRb?p=preview) which shows a solution which isn't satisfactory for my use case.

Here is the solutions html:

```
<accordion>
  <accordion-group>
      <accordion-heading>
          <span ng-click="foo()">Try clicking me!</span>
      </accordion-heading>
      Some Body 3
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

However **the ng-click event only fires if you click on the span text**. If you click just outside of the text the accordion still opens or closes without any click event.

To fix this I tried making the spans width & height 100% and setting display: block.
I also considered removing the padding entirely but I was wondering if there is a better way than hacking at it.

Does anyone know how to attach the ng-click event to the entire accordian group? Or how to make the span fill the entire group?

My entire code:

```
  <accordion close-others="true">
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="question in level">
        <accordion-heading style="padding: 0">
            <div style="display: block; margin: 0px" ng-click="set_question(question.title)">{{ question.title }}</div>
            <i class="icon-check" ng-show="has_solved_all"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="question.content"></span>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
    <br>
    Question Open: {{ question_open }}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle open/collapse events of Accordion in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642082/handle-open-collapse-events-of-accordion-in-angular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need `ng-click` specific solution? There is an `is-open` attribute which you can watch for, and which triggers on opening/closing of an accordion.

Comment: Perhaps I can use is-open. I'm searching documentation now.
My problem more specifically is I have an ng-repeat="question in questions". Each question opens up in an accordian. Then down the bottom of the page it says which question you're viewing.

Comment: oops - looks similar. In any case - I think we can mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: is it a good idea to use $watch. As angular does not encourage using $watch. as we are interfaring with the digest cycle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using new versions of Angular, an event called `isOpenChange`, handle it.

```
<accordion>
  <accordion-group (isOpenChange)="foo()">
   <button class="btn btn-link btn-block clearfix" accordion-heading type="button">
    <div class="pull-left float-left">Header Title</div>
   </button>

   <div>Some Body 3</div>
 </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a top level div under accordion heading or move

```
<i class="icon-check" ng-show="has_solved_all"></i>
```

inside the div element -

```
<div style="display: block; margin: 0px"
```

This should do the magic. 
Below works for me-

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" >
  <accordion-heading>
    <div ng-click="opened(group, $index)">
      <span>{{group.title}}</span>
    </div>
  </accordion-heading>
  {{group.content}}
</accordion-group>
```

Modify and verify in the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/B3LC1X?p=preview
console log.
I know the question is old but others can use this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you entend to add another click with the one existe of the the open event. I suggest to add the directive bellow inside the  tag:

```
myApp.directive('functionClick',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        terminal: true,
        controller: 'NameOfController',
         templateUrl: "templateFunctionClick.html",
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl){
        }
    }

});

<accordion-group  is-open="status.open">
  <accordion-heading >
    {{headerName}}
    <function-click></function-click>
  </accordion-heading>
</accordion-group>
```

Where the templateFunctionClick.html:

```
<a ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();clickMeFunction()" ><span>Click Me!</span> </a>
```

be sure to add $event.stopPropagation(); in order to don't call in same time the click of toggelOpen().