# Angular UI Accordion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to find out how to watch Angular UI's accordion `is-open` event so I can have a call back when ever any of my accordions are closed.

This is the basic structure of my accordion's (refined just to show one.)
One thing to note is that these are actually static content, nothings dynamic.

```
<accordion-group is-open="true">

  <accordion-heading>
    <h3>Some Header</h3>
  </accordion-heading>

  <h4>Some pretty awesome content!</h4>
</accordion-group>
```

My controller

```
.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;    
  $scope.$watch('groups[0].open', function (isOpen) {    
    if (!isOpen) {    
      console.log('First group was opened');    
    }
  });  
});
```

**[Heres a demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/teiTTl?p=preview)**
I'm getting the `console.log` to fire once upon load, but not when I close any other accordions. 
Any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a sample for us?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/teiTTl?p=preview

Comment: Awesome, I was able to figure out a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're finding the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15642577/1216976).  That isn't working for you, because you're not using `ng-repeat` to generate your accordions.  Instead, bind to the `is-open` attribute:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {
$scope.oneAtATime = true;    
$scope.first = {
  open: true
}
  $scope.$watch('first.open', function (isOpen) {      
    console.log('First group was toggled');    
  }); 
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
 <accordion-group is-open="first.open">

  <accordion-heading>
    <h3>Some Header</h3>
  </accordion-heading>

  <h4>Some pretty awesome content!</h4>
</accordion-group>
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HCqcZMlRb20fLymxLrsO?p=preview)

Comment: This is great, thanks for the answer, but I do need to function to run when ever the accordion is toggled. Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using a ng-click event ? That's clearly better to bind your function on the "click" event than watching it. So, if you can avoid it..

Comment: `ng-click` won't work in this scenario.  He only wants it to be triggered on open, not any click.

Comment: Actually a click event would work, since the even will fire when the accordion opens and closes. I'm using a customs scrolling container for some mobile events, but for its size to update, I need to call it manually. So I created a simple function to do this but when I try to place the ng-click on the `accordion-group`, it doesn't fire. 

http://plnkr.co/edit/teiTTl?p=preview