# Why does AngularJS strip out data- attributes when using ng-bind-html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, escaping

I am using a contentEditable div to enable users to format their articles. I do some processing on the html content and persist it.

I am using `ng-bind-html` to render the result when viewers want to read the article. I don't want to use `$sce.trustAsHtml` because I still want AngularJS to sanitize the user input and because I don't trust all the input. All I want is for AngularJS sanitization to allow some attributes on elements. It seems to strip ID, and data- attributes. (but keeps class and title) .

Is data- attributes considered harmful? How can an attacker may use them to attack the end user? And is there a way to use them safely and let Angular not strip them out?

Here's an example:

```
article.body = '<p data-guid="afasfa-afasfafas-faf-asasf" class="guid-tagged">Yes this is my article</p>';
<article ng-bind-html='article.body'></article>
```

Here's what Angular outputs inside the article tag (notice the stripped out data- attribute):

```
<p class="guid-tagged">Yes this is my article</p>
```

Thanks

Comment: The sanitizer has a hard-coded list of allowed attributes, which means there is no built in feature to add your own, and data-attributes will by default be removed. You cak check the source https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment, `ng-bind-html` passes the data through a sanitizer. This sanitizer removes a number of attributes from all input passed in it. This issue may help explain more: [ngSanitize issue concerning whitelisting attributes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5900). This [part of the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L216) includes all the attributes considered valid and therefore left untouched by ngSanitize.

Answer (score 0):

While the Angular and ngSanitize crew sort this out, I found [this thread helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642082/handle-open-collapse-events-of-accordion-in-angular) to create a workaround. In particular, the answer speaking to a **dynamically defined Property**.

Binding to `is-open` with such a property, I was able to attach click handlers on anchor tags *after* ngSanitize had finished sanitizing.

Here's the  HTML after being sanitized, note that I'm using `cite` to store the target anchor id as it is one of the attributes that ngSanitize ignores.  (You could try using the `href` but I wanted to leave that alone):

`Please see <a href='#' cite='#another_faq'>here</a>`

The code in the setter for the Property (see the referenced SO above) then manipulates DOM events which I believe is counter to the Angular methodology but sometimes you have to stop banging your head and get it to work:

`if (isOpened)
    $('p.faq.answer').eq(item.position).find('a[cite]').each ->
        $(this).bind 'click', () ->
            $($(this).attr('cite')).click()`

And then make sure you have the proper anchor with target id of `#another_faq`, in this case.