# The id from binded html does not appear in the DOM

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ng-bind-html and have a div with a class and an id.

```
<div class="myCustomClass" id="myCustomID">My Content</div>
```

When I inspect the element I can see the class but the ID is missing. Here is a working plunkr illustrating the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/iHeQQI?p=preview

Comment: Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628126/ng-bind-html-doesnt-work-properly) maybe it'll help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28782696/4088809 seems like id is not in the whitelist of attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process you html source with `$sce` service like this:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div id="myID" class="myClass">Inspecting this element shows the class but not the ID</div>');
});
```